# w3c css validator parse error

Tags: css, w3c-validation

I am getting a unusual error. Trying to remove the last of my w3c erros in css and am left with the following :

```
.2-col-width-left { float:left; margin-top:10px; width:63%; }
.2-col-width-right { padding-top:10px; float:right; width:37%; text-align:right; }
.3-col-width-left { float:left; margin-top:10px; width:60%; }
.3-col-width-right { padding-top:10px;float:right; width:40%; text-align:right; }
.4-col-full { padding:5px 0; width:100%; text-align:center; }
.4-col-title { margin-top:10px; width:100%; }
```

I am getting a `PARSE ERROR` but have no idea why. Have googled but with no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your selectors are starting with numbers. Your selectors should only begin with a letter or *escaped* number. See here for more details:

http://www.markinns.com/articles/full/using_numbers_as_css_class_or_id_values

And

[Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors)

Comment: opps, now i feel stupid. Thanks, I will accept when it lets me!

Comment: @AlbaClan Nothing to feel stupid about, this rule is not the most obvious and if it weren't for the fact I'd made the same mistake before, I would have had no clue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, according to the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier),

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); they **cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item).

But you can escape them. Just add `\00003` before the number at the beginning:

```
.\000032-col-width-left { float:left; margin-top:10px; width:63%; }
.\000032-col-width-right { padding-top:10px; float:right; width:37%; text-align:right; }
.\000033-col-width-left { float:left; margin-top:10px; width:60%; }
.\000033-col-width-right { padding-top:10px;float:right; width:40%; text-align:right; }
.\000034-col-full { padding:5px 0; width:100%; text-align:center; }
.\000034-col-title { margin-top:10px; width:100%; }
```